# Redis DB not getting connected in jenkins

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I have below code  in which I can make a connection to the redis by adding the redisconfig.setdatabase which works fine in local but when i ran it in jenkins i got the assertion error which gets reproduced in local if i remove the db index settings from my code.how to make sure it works in jenkins as well. as the below setting works fine in my local

```
 @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
       RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(config.getRedisHost(),config.getRedisPort());
     redisConfig.setDatabase(1);

        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = jedisPoolConfigTest();

        JedisClientConfiguration clientConfig = JedisClientConfiguration.builder()
                .usePooling()
                .poolConfig(poolConfig)
                .and()
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30L))
                .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30L))
                .build();
        JedisConnectionFactory factory= new JedisConnectionFactory(redisConfig, clientConfig);
      
       return factory;
    }
```

Comment: Please post Jenkins error.

Comment: jedis cant make a connection,resource poolnot found

Comment: What do you mean "remove the db index settings from my code"?